# Flutter iOS application couldn't run with error app_settings not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, dart

I have a flutter app, everything fine with Android studio and run on Android system smoothly without any problem
When I moved to iOS version, I start facing multiple problems and I solve it all, the last problem is missing app_settings, but the folder already created on the project root.

**- I tried to run it through Xcode, it shows an error as shows on the picture:**
[image]

**- I tried to run this command (Flutter run) inside the project directory, it shows this error:**
[image]

**I tried this steps with no solutions:**

Changed the rate_my_app version in Pubspec.yaml and Pubspec.lock

Then delete those files:
podfile - podfile.lock - pods folder - build folder

Then run those command inside the project directory:
pod init
add this lines to podfile:
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'FirebaseAuth'

add this line to AppDelegate.swift
import FirebaseAuth

add this line to lib/models/user/user_model.dart
import 'package:app_settings/app_settings.dart';

then run this command
pod install

Then from Xcode > Product > Clean build folder

The run the app

FYI, the project shows a missing framework which I couldn't find any solution for that except deleting the record from the project every time it shows up.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution.**

The problem was with ios/Flutter directory files, it was missing and some corrupted files.

**What did I do is** creating another Flutter project with the same project and Bundl name, then I copied the Flutter folder from the new project to my current one.

That fixed everything for me.